# OpenIdConnect Behaviour Visual Studio vs Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an asp.net core 5 website that I've deployed to an Azure App Service.

Within *Startup.ConfigureServices* it has the following:

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                              .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                              .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

*Startup.Configure* includes the following:

```
app.UseAuthentication(); 
app.UseAuthorization();
```

In the App Registration on Azure, I have on "ID tokens" checked on the "Authentication" tab:

[image]

When I browse to the deployed site in Azure I get redirected to:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https://azapp-contactcentre-surveyadmin-dev-001.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/**callback**&client_id=xxx&scope=openid
> profile email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=xxx

However, if I run the same site from Visual Studio, then the redirect is:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44381/**signin-oidc**&response_type=id_token&scope=openid
> profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637719649643589555.Y2U0YmY1MjQtZjVmNS00ZWQ0LTlkMzAtNWRkMzBmOTMwNmQ5NWUzNWJmNTItMTAzZC00ZTUwLTk0ODMtYjVlZjgzM2NhYWIx&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.1.16.1.0&state=xxx

I am able to login and use the site in both cases but I'd like to understand why the behaviour differs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the Authentication feature on Azure App Service (aka EasyAuth).
The redirect URI (.auth/login/aad/callback) looks like the one it uses.
If you configure authentication in your code, it is most likely better to disable this at App Service level.